# Nested Jest mock fails unless previously defined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Defining a Jest mock with `jest.fn()` in the callback of a `jest.fn()` mock does not seem to work. If the mock is defined first outside of the callback it works correctly.

Is it supported to define a mock in the callback?

```
it('passes', () => {
  const mock = jest.fn();
  const object = {method1: jest.fn(() => ({method2: mock}))};

  object.method1().method2();

  expect(object.method1().method2).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});

it('does not pass', () => {
  const object = {method1: jest.fn(() => ({method2: jest.fn()}))};

  object.method1().method2();

  expect(object.method1().method2).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your second example does not pass is due to the fact that every time you call `object.method1()` you are returning a new spy in the `method2` property.

So, when you execute `object.method1().method2();` you are creating a mock function and executing it through the call to `method2`. This mock function is indeed being executed.

When you call `object.method1().method2` in your expectation statement, you are getting a newly created mock function in `method2`. This mock function has not been called, so your test fails.